# mkdir with ascending sequential suffix and mv one file into each folder

Tags: linux, bash, mkdir, mv

```
ls -1 | sort -V > txt_list
```

and

```
cat txt_list
```

gives

```
ASOFJ.txt
BJWIF.txt
CWORI.txt
...
```

I want to `mkdir` with suffix in ascending order like `folder_1`, `folder_2`, `folder_3`

and `mv ASOFJ.txt folder_1` , `mv BJWIF.txt folder_2`, `mv CWORI.txt folder_3`

I have tried

```
num=0 ; while read p ; do ( num=$(expr $num + 1) && mkdir "folder_"$num && mv $p "folder_"$num ) ; done < txt_list
```

But it didn't work.

Do you have any idea on a one-liner that executes the above?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add all attempts to your question by editing it, along with your attempts to resolve the problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
let c=0; for i in $('ls'); do c=$((c+1)); mkdir -p folder_$c; mv $i folder_$c; done
```

This should do it, I think.

Explanation:

- define variable `c`
- go over each element in ls

  - add 1 to `c`
  - create folder with suffix `c`
  - move element to folder

Comment: Thank you Malik! May I know how to modify to add leading zeros to the folder name i.e. folder_001, folder_002 and folder_003?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=1
while read line
do
    mkdir "folder_${counter}" && mv $line "folder_${counter}"
    ((counter++))
done <<< $(ls -1 | sort -V)
```